# Why does this curl request not submit the POST data?

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to use cURL (in a bash script) to load a page on my ISPs site containing my monthly data usage.

Here's the relevent form from the page:

```
<form method="post" id="Login" name="Login" action="https://signon.bigpond.com/login" class="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="https://my.bigpond.com/mybigpond/default.do?ref=Net-Header-MyBigPond1"/>

    <div class="loginModule roundify">
        <div class="loginForm">

            <div class="formRow error">
                <label for="userName">
                    Username<span class="reqField">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="username" name="username" size="30" maxlength="200" onkeypress="EnterKeyPress(event)" value=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="formRow error">
                <label for="password">
                    Password<span class="reqField">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="password" tabindex="2" id="password" name="password" size="30" maxlength="50" onkeypress="EnterKeyPress(event)"/>                                     
            </div>

           <div class="buttons">
                <input class="submit roundify" type="submit" value="Log in" onclick="setCookieForUser();this.disabled=true;document.forms['Login'].submit();" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that the submit button doesn't have a name.

The function called when text is entered into the form:

```
function EnterKeyPress(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

                if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
                else if (e.which) code = e.which;

                if ( code == 13 && document.getElementById("username").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("password").value.length > 0 ) {
                    document.forms['Login'].submit();
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }
}
```

The cURL command line:

```
 $ curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" --verbose --location --cookie-jar "/tmp/bigpond.cookies" --cookie "/tmp/bigpond.cookies" -o "/tmp/bigpond.html" --data-urlencode "username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD" https://signon.bigpond.com/login?goto=https://my.bigpond.com/mybigpond/default.do?ref=Net-Header-MyBigPond1
```

However, the saved html file (/tmp/bigpond.html) is just the logon page still, with text added saying I forgot to enter my username and password. **Why is cURL not sending the POST data or what am I doing wrong?**

Update: Answered my own question. See below for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was passing the POST data to cURL in one argument was causing the data to be mangled when cURL did the URL encoding. The correct usage is to pass each field as a separate argument like so:

```
curl --data-urlencode "username=XXXXXX" --data-urlencode "password=XXXXXX" ...
```

Comment: @Sun No, that would mean one variable named `username` equal to value `XXXXX&password=XXXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -L -s -d "username=<USER NAME>&password=<PASSWORD>" https://signon.bigpond.com/login
```

And  compare the headers of `cURL` with `LiveHttpHeaders firefox module`

Comment: Doesn't work - same result as my command. It just redirects back to the login page with additional text added saying the username and password wasn't entered.

Comment: Add `-v` switch to trace what's going on, and compare it to the LiveHttpHeaders firefox module.

Comment: Instead of -v I used --trace-ascii and compared the headers with what LiveHttpHeaders was showing. The POST data was being mangled because I wasn't passing it to cURL correclty. Your answer isn't the solution to the question, but it did lead me in the right direction! Thanks.